# Question about means on linear maps from vector space of bounded sequences to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, operator-theory

The definitions I am working with:

1. $B$ is the vector space of bounded sequences $a=(a_n), n\in\mathbb{Z}$ for which there exists $C>0$ such that $|a_n|\leq C, \forall n$

2.
Mean on $B$ is a linear map from $\,u:B\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $inf_na_n\leq\mu(a)\leq sup_n a_n$ for all sequences in $B$.

The claim is that there exists shift-invariant mean but apparently I need to show the following first.

Want to show that there is a sequence $\mu_n$ of means such that $\forall a\in B$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}|\mu_n(a^s)-\mu_n(a)|=0$ a is a sequence and $a^s$ is the sequence with terms shifted such that $a_{n+1}$ is in nth position.

What should I be thinking about?

Comment: So these $(a_n)$ are complex numbers? ie. Is $B = \ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I am not sure what that notation means.. but they are not necessarily complex numbers. Just any bounded sequence.

Comment: That was my question - bounded sequences of what? vectors? operators? elephants?

Answer (score 0):

Let $D$ be the set of those $(a_n)_n\in B$ for which $f((a_n)_n)=\lim_{j\to \infty}(2j+1)^{-1}\sum_{n=-j}^{n=j}a_n$ exists......Let $E=\bar D$. The function $f$ extends uniquely to a functional $f'$ on $E$ with $||f'||=1$ , and by the Hahn-Banach theorem,we can extend $f'$ to a functional $u$ on $B$ with $||u||=1$. There are some details omitted, for you to work out. This is an example of a generalized limit :If $(a_n)_n$ converges to $r$ then $u((a_n)_n)=r$.